# PHP Array filled with information form database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

This is how i put my information from the database in a array:

```
$sql = "SELECT city, read FROM location";
$info = mysql_query($sql);
$read = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($info)){
    $read[] = $row;
}
```

This is a piece of the output of `$read` (there are 40 city`s in the table):

```
Array ([0] => Array ([city] => New York [read] => false) [1] => Array ([city] => Paris [read] => true ))
```

Now I want to check if the read value of a city is true then echo something.

I don`t know how to do this do I need a for loop or just a if statement?

Can someone help?

Comment: you can just if at the same time you are putting data into `$read[]`

Comment: **Don't** use the **deprecated and insecure** `mysql_*`-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7. Use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Still using an older version so that`s no issue

Comment: @user3356007 That doesn't mean `mysql_*` functions are any less insecure.

Comment: You're script won't be as secure as it could be + it won't be future proof. It's better to use the non deprecated libraries now, while you're developing. Otherwise you will get much more to rewrite later on.

Comment: your code is failing here; know why? least for what you posted and if that is your actual code you're using

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I understand thx for the feedback!

Comment: @Fred-ii- what do you mean?

Comment: BTW, how could you possibly have different keys in your sub-arrays (`city` vs. `locatie`), and how do you manage to get `bool` values for `read` from your request (instead of `string`) ?

Comment: Tell you what; try this along with the answers given and see what they missed, then post your error `$info = mysql_query($sql); 
if(!$info) { echo "Failed: " . mysql_error(); }`

Comment: I feel like you are sending out the wrong message here by accepting an answer that did not show the obvious error you made in your query.

Comment: @Fred-ii- don`t see any error and the array is getting filled? there is nog Fail in the query?

Comment: Probably what you posted isn't what you're really using because `READ` is a MySQL reserved word https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html and find it hard to believe that your query didn't fail. Again; least not for what you posted. I know my reserved words quite well ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- You are right about that i typed it from another screen if have changed it! sorry en THX for your feedback!

Comment: @roberto06 You are right my fault I have changed it thx!

Comment: @user3356007 I had to do a rollback to a previous revision. Please leave the question as it was, since others may get downvoted because of it. It's fine as it is now.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I edited at the same time as you rolled back, looks like the system went with my edit instead of yours, sorry.

Comment: @roberto06 no worries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function checkCityRead($city){
    foreach($read as $r){
        if($r['city']==$city){
            if($r['read']=='true'){
                //do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

or if want it as a general loop for all cities

```
foreach($read as $r){
    if($r['read']=='true'){
        //do something
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

As many recommendations in the comments, you should not use the deprecated library `mysql`, and also you should your query if it has been executed or not "Credits to @Fred-ii", so your code could be like this:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
} else{
    $sql = "SELECT city, `read` FROM location";
    $info = mysqli_query($sql, $con);
    if(!$info){
        echo mysqli_error($con);
    } else{
        $read = array();
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($info)){
              $read[] = $row;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try this out now!

Comment: @user3356007 just edited the first if statement in the function

Comment: this answer missed something in the query

Comment: @Fred-ii- yeah you are right he should make sure that the query runs, but the question was about looping for result not about the query itself, so i didn't notice that.

Comment: @Mohammad I feel that for future users to the question should be advised of their use of the `READ` reserved word and is an important detail to not have mentioned as I have up there.

Comment: `READ` needs to be ticked `\`` ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You need a [`foreach` statement](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) :

```
foreach ($read as $value) {
    if ($value['read'] == true)
        echo 'something';
}
```

And, as stated by Magnus Eriksson in his comment, **you should really [refrain from using `mysql_*` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)**.

EDIT (as caught and suggested by **Fred -ii-**) : `read` is a reserved mySQL keyword, thus your query should have failed if you didn't include backticks, as follows :

```
$sql = "SELECT city, `read` FROM location";
```

Side note : You might want to compare `$value['read']` to `'true'` instead of `true` (`string` and not `bool`) as I'm pretty sure `mysql_fetch_assoc()` always returns `string`-type values :

```
foreach ($read as $value) {
    if ($value['read'] == 'true')
        echo 'something';
}
```

Comment: this answer missed something in the query

Comment: I saw your comments on OP's question, and I have to say I am at a loss to find what I've missed. I'll wait for OP to output the result of `mysql_error()`, but if he doesn't, could you eventually tell me what I missed ?

Comment: Nice catch with the `READ` reserved keyword, I have to admit I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: One gets to know them almost by heart after a while ;-)

Comment: You could modify your answer in accordance with what they did post. If they did not tick `\`` that column, then it's failing. If they did tick it, then they didn't post their real code and is a bit deceiving for (future) visitors to the question/answers.

Comment: @Fred-ii- and Roberto You guys are right I have changed it in the question thx for your attentiveness

Comment: @user3356007 You haven't replaced the right `read`. It's the one in the SQL query that you should escape with backticks (`\``), there's no need for renaming the PHP variable `$read`.

Comment: @user3356007 Just don't go editing your question with the new code around that column, because we would have done all that for nothing ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have changed it! Sorry for all the problems I will be more accurate next time!